# SQL Server does not update sdb.dbo.sysdac_instances_internal after deleting database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

When I register my SQL Server 2012 database as a data-Tier application, then turn around and delete the database, the record created in the 'sdb.dbo.sysdac_instances_internal' table is still there.

What's worse if I restore the database with an older backup, it keeps the version number of the deleted database. My deploys are failing because the database 'drifted'. I have version-dependent logic in my pre/post deploy scripts where I expect a version to correspond to a specific schema version.

Is there a way to wipe out the sysdac_instances_internal record on database drops but restore it during database restore? I know I can register/unregister as a data-tier app, but I can't reconcile that way. The schema and version seems out of sync/disconnected here.